# is gtk_application_new redundant function?

Tags: gtk

on web-browsing for examples on gtk, i came across some examples where the `main()` starts with `gtk_window_new()` & `gtk_main()` function calls while some other examples with `gtk_application_new()` & `gtk_application_run()`. What is the difference between both the approaches? Any good article explaining the difference would be good.

Answer (score 2):

[GtkApplication reference documention](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html#GtkApplication.description) does a fine job explaining this (although you should click through to parent GApplication as well as the majority of functionality is implemented there):

> GtkApplication is a class that handles many important aspects of a
>   GTK+ application in a convenient fashion, without enforcing a
>   one-size-fits-all application model.
>
> Currently, GtkApplication handles
>   GTK+ initialization, application uniqueness, session management,
>   provides some basic scriptability and desktop shell integration by
>   exporting actions and menus and manages a list of toplevel windows
>   whose life-cycle is automatically tied to the life-cycle of your
>   application.

Basically GtkApplication does several things you would have had to do yourself before this. Using GtkApplication has no major down sides so even if you don't think you need it right now, you probably should use it in new projects.

Comment: That being said, GtkApplication does **not** deprecate `gtk_main()` (you can still write non-GtkApplication applications), and you would still need `gtk_window_new()` anyway.